# Converting stream to path/filename without writing to physical disk

Tags: java, file, path, stream, filesystems

I'm using a proprietary Java API (source code not disclosed) which has a method defined in one of its interfaces:

```
Foo.bar(String fileName, String formatName);
```

The problem with this method is that it takes a `String fileName`. I wish there were a method which would take a `File file` or some kind of *stream* instead, but such a method does not exist. Decompiling the .class file shows that the API internally does a `new File(fileName)`, but mimicking its entire behaviour is too dauntning and risky.

In my code I have created a stream, and I want to be able to call `bar()` without writing anything to disk first (at leat not physically).

Is there any way I can trick `Foo.bar()` into accepting my stream? Perhaps by utilizing some virtual filesystem in Java?

We're using Java 1.7 on this.

Answer (score 1):

Does this cover your needs?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html

> The java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider class allows you to develop a
>   custom file system provider. A custom file system provider is useful
>   in the following situations:
>
> **Developing a memory-based or zip-file-based file system**

By extending the class [java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html) 
and overriding its methods `newInputStream` or `newOutputStream` you should be able to provide your stream as a file.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'll look into it. Right off the bat, do you know if it's also applicable for Java 1.7 (I edited my question now)?

Comment: Ah, first sentence: _The NIO.2 API introduced in the Java SE 7 release_ ... :-)

Comment: According to Javadoc of FileSystemProvider it is available as of Java 1.7.

Comment: I guess you want the API to write to your stream, but have to provide it with a filename. Even if your stream was constructed from a file(name) in the first place, the API in question would not get your stream-object when opening the file, it would get a new stream. It seems to me that the only way of mapping a stream to a filename in a way that is reversible would be to create a custom filesystem managing stream-objects by name.

Comment: I think you are right, Rolf Rander, and I was thinking along those lines myself. It made me stuble upon Google Jimfs (an in-memory FS implementing the Java NIO File APIs). I tried saving to a new path created using these libs and then feeding its name to the original bar() method - seems to work! Some more testing to be done, but I just think Jimfs might have solved it :-) Thanks for the comment!

Comment: As it turned out this did not actually work. The closed API would always read from disk, not knowing about the newly-created memory FS. It *might* be possible to trick the environment (perhaps the JVM?) somehow, but instead of this I decompiled the .class files and mimicked the behaviour of the closed API in my own code. It was not straight forward as it was necessary to lure out unexposed methods and classes, in order to be able to reuse them in my own code.